# Putting a 3commas signal into alert() in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

I'm using this strategy:

if (not na(vrsi))

```
if (ta.crossover(vrsi, overSold) and ta.crossover(source, lower))
    strategy.entry("RSI_BB_L", strategy.long, comment="RSI_BB_L")
    alert("BUY alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)       
    
else
    if (ta.crossunder(vrsi, overBought) and ta.crossunder(source, upper))
        strategy.close(id = "RSI_BB_L", comment="close")
        alert("SELL alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

I need to get this string into the buy alert message:

{
"message_type": "bot",
"bot_id": 6517352,
"email_token": "d106a1fc-6b41-410c-9532-38253f7273c5",
"delay_seconds": 0
}

When I try this:

alert("{"message_type": "bot", "bot_id": 6517352, "email_token": "d106a1fc-6b41-410c-9532-38253f7273c5","delay_seconds": 0}", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

I get : mismatched input 'message_type' expecting ')'

Any suggestions would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Use '' to escape "".

```
alert('{ "message_type": "bot", "bot_id": 6517352, "email_token": "d106a1fc-6b41-410c-9532-38253f7273c5", "delay_seconds": 0 }')
```